# as3 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. -enterframe

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

i'm making a simple game and i'm still learning as3
i want to hit test object on the stage , bila1 with omidae1 if hittestobject gotoframe 
all the objects are on the stage with corect instancename, maintimeline as3 below
everything works fine but i get the null error

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   testpeframe_fla::MainTimeline/**bling**()[testpeframe_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:32]

So the problem is Event.ENTER_FRAME, bling
 how can i fix that ?

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent ;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
btnt.visible = false;

butondrr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler2);
function fl_MouseClickHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void
{   
var myTween:Tween = new Tween(bila1, "x", Strong.easeOut, 500, 700, 1, true);
var myTweenm:Tween = new Tween(bila1, "y", Strong.easeOut, 250, 600, 8, true);
} 

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bling);
function bling(event:Event):void 
{

if(bila1.hitTestObject(omidae1)) 
{
omidae1.visible = false;
btnt.visible = true;
}
}
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bling);
stop();
btnt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

Comment: Did you instantiate the display objects on runtime or did you created on stage and later referenced them by calling their instance id?

Comment: i created the objects on the stage and later calling their instance

Comment: i run  the code below and nothing shows       an if (bila1 == null) {
  trace("bila1 nuull");
}

if (omidae1 == null) {
  trace("omid nuull");  
}
if (btnt == null) {
  trace("btnt nuull");  
}

Comment: Try it this way instead : `trace(omidae1);` & see the value

Comment: nothing shows the same ..

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new frame at frame 1 (move all the other frames up one, frame 1 -> frame 2, etc)

What might be happening is that you're trying to access things before the swf is completely loaded.

In frame one add:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, ready);
stop();

function ready(e:Event):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, ready);
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Comment: the soluion is not working just a blank screen i think because of stop(); if i remove stop in the code above the same error and i was thinking about it and i want to say there is a delay until bila1 hit omidae1 and second  i  tried to copy all objects on the stage on 2 frames and put the action code in frame 2 so  frame 1 with all the objects wil load first but the same

Comment: i think i know the problem var myTweenm:Tween = new Tween(bila1, "y", Strong.easeOut, 250, 600, 8, true); the hittestobject stop only when is on the x and y specified so first hit working and after there is no  hit with omidae beacuse is not visible i must break the loop or something to hit only once i added trace after hittestobject and seen alot of that

Comment: even i think i konow where is  the problem i don't know how to fix it..i tried some to put  myTweenm.stop(); right after hittestobject and the bila1 stop right after i get the same eror

Comment: i think i fix it stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bling);  replace with addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bling);